# <no value> appearing in idb

Tags: debugging, fortran90

I have a problem with the program I'm writing for my diploma-thesis.

I'm using a code that calculates some flow problems and now I'm adding an application to it.

For this I need a matrix and get it from the old code.

This is called `AA_save_SP` and is `real(sp)`.

I want to invert the matrix and give it to a subroutine as `matrix_in` (also `ral(sp)` and same `size(n,n)`).

In the subroutine I define a new matrix called matrix_solve, it is `real(sp)` and has the size `(n,2*n)`.

From the idb, I get the message: `"Program received signal SIGSEGV"` and if I'm looking up the values in the Matrix they are `<no value>`.

So I did not do anything with the matrix and all the other times I defined a variable it worked fine and I never had this problem.

The subroutine:

```
  SUBROUTINE BL3D_LIB_invert_matrix(matrix_in,n,matrix_invert)
! Parameter
! Arguments
  REAL    , INTENT(IN   ) :: matrix_in(n,n)
  INTEGER , INTENT(IN   ) :: n
  REAL    , INTENT(  OUT) :: matrix_invert(n,n)
! Locals
  REAL                    :: matrix_solve(n,2*n)
  INTEGER                 :: k, i


  matrix_solve(1:n,1:n) = matrix_in(1:n,1:n)
  matrix_solve(1:n,n+1:2*n) = 0.

  DO i = 1, n
    matrix_solve(i,n+i) = -1.
  END DO


  call math_solve(matrix_solve,n,n,k,1.e-12_sp)

  IF (k.eq.0) THEN

    matrix_invert(1:n,1:n) = matrix_solve(1:n,n+1:2*n)

  ELSE
    WRITE (*,*) "Fehler beim invertieren der Koeff.-Matrix."
  END IF

  END SUBROUTINE BL3D_LIB_invert_matrix
```

Hopefully there is someone who could help me!

Comment: I can't immediately see anything wrong with your subroutine.  Show us how you are calling it, preferably post as small an amount of code as you can which is compilable and which (re-)produces the error.

Comment: Try printing `matrix_solve` to screen before and after `call math_solve(...)` to see if maybe that subroutine is causing the problem. But definitely more information is going to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I've found a solution. I just inserted: matrix_solve(1:n,1:2*n) = 0. before matrix_solve(1:n,1:n) = matrix_in(1:n,1:n)

Now it works, I don't know why I have to write first a zero into the matrix, but it works...